# Accessing changes in Database while Transaction is Running

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, transactions, .net-1.1

I'm developing a .NET application that interacts with a database. In a method I begin a SQL Transaction and modify some values in `table1`, after I'm done with the changes (but still haven't committed the transaction) I launch a `Threading.Thread` to go update values in `table2` using data from `table1`.

Will this thread read the modified values? Or will it load the data as it was before transaction was begun?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on if the second thread is using the same connection/session in which the transaction was started. If it is, then it can see the changes made so far during that transaction. If it is a different connection, it will be blind to those changes until they are committed.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `RepeatableRead` or `ReadUncommitted` transaction isolation levels for the transaction in the second thread will allow you to read the uncommitted data from table1.

More info on transaction isolation levels:

[IsolationLevel Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.isolationlevel.aspx)

[Set Transaction Isolation Level (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx)

Different is the question how will you ensure that the data is written to table1 before reading it and updating table2, but this depends on your .NET application implementation.